# MongoDB Query, update specific field if value is not null

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have an object **"input"** and will be passed to query like a parameter:

```
var input = {
    id: 1,
    componentId: x,
    commands: [...],
    user: [...],
}
```

And the collection **"testCollection"**:

```
testCollection = {
    id: 1,
    model: {
        stepComponents: [
           {  
            componentId: x
            command: [...],
            user: [...],
           }
         ]
    }
}
```

My question is how can I update a specific field on **"testCollection"** and skip the update if it is undefined or null.
That means if **"input.user"** is undefined/null, then not update **"user"** field.

The update query sample is below:

```
testCollection.update(
  {
    _id: objectId(input.id),
    'model.stepComponents.componentId': input.componentId
  },
  {
    'inputs': input.inputs,
    'model.stepComponents.$.commands': input.commands,
    'model.stepComponents.$.users': input.users,
  },
  { upsert: true },
);
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was struck at the same problem and solved by below solution

```
  let params= {
      id: req.body.id, componentId: req.body.x, commands: req.body...,
  }

  ;
  for(let prop in params) if(!params[prop]) delete params[prop];//it will remove fields who are undefined or null 

  testCollection.findOneAndUpdate( {
      _id: req.params.id
  }

  , params);
```

Comment: Sorry for my late response, it solved my problem, thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Try this one:

```
testCollection.update(
{
  _id: objectId(input.id),
  user: {$ne: null}
},
{
    $set: {input}
}
```

);

Comment: It's not suitable for my case, anw, thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 2):

You can try to use [exists](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/exists/)

```
db.collection.find({ "fieldToCheck": { $exists: true, $ne: null } })
```